# How to get SceneKit objects to not bounce at all

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm trying to make a part of my app which simulates dropping a set of books (the grey rectangles) one on top of another, on a table. Attached is a video.

[image]

However, unlike books in real life, these books bounce slightly after each one is dropped, to the point the pile of books falls over!

I've set the `restitution` to zero on each book's `physicsBody`, but this still happens:

```
private func buildBookNode(at position: SCNVector3, rotation: Measurement<UnitAngle> = Measurement(value: 0, unit: .radians)) -> SCNNode {
    let book = SCNBox(width: 0.4, height: 0.1, length: 0.3, chamferRadius: 0)
    let bookNode = SCNNode(geometry: book)
    bookNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
    bookNode.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = true
    bookNode.physicsBody?.friction = 2.0
    bookNode.physicsBody?.mass = 0.3
    bookNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    bookNode.position = position
    bookNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, rotation.converted(to: .radians).value)
    return bookNode
}
```

What properties to I need to set to prevent the books bouncing on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to control the bouncing is

bookNode.physicsBody?.damping = 0.9.

This may lead to slow motion of books. So a better idea is using contactDelegate to dynamic change the damping after collision.